How to keep the div 100% of the parent container when scaling the div?
I am trying to build a canvas like element using div.
I have a div element that is acting as a canvas, this div element can zoom and pan. This div.canvas element is placed inside a container. I achieve the zooming and panning effects using css transforms scale and translate.

(the black is the container, the green is the div.canvas and inner red square is inner element)
Every time, I zoom out the div(acting as canvas) width and height is also scaled down and not is not 100% to the container.
here's a codesandbox that can replicate the problem. (use +, - keys for zooming)


// import "./styles.css";

let scale = 1;

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "+") {
    scale += 0.2;
  } else if (e.key === "-") {
    scale -= 0.2;
  }
  // console.log("scale: ", scale);
  document.getElementById("canvas").style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
});
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: brown;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="canvas" id="canvas">
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="./index.mjs" type="module"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>



You'll notice every time you scale down pressing - key, the div.canvas becomes smaller as well.
how can I ensure everytime I zoom, it affects only the contents inside the div.canvas instead of the div itself or how can I make sure that the div.canvas is always 100% of the parent container?

Edit:
My endgoal is something like this, but have infinite canvas(green div) fill the container.


You should change the scale of the child elements of canvas instead of canvas itself:


let scale = 1;
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "+") scale += 0.2;
  if (e.key === "-") scale -= 0.2;
  
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const children = canvas.children // get the child elements
  for(const child of children){
    child.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`; // pass the scale to the childs only
  }
});
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background-color: brown;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="canvas" id="canvas">
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="./index.mjs" type="module"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>




Hey thanks for the answer, This is something that I had thought of, but using this method it can have performance issues when there many objects. Plus, I won't be able to zoom to a particular point on the div.canvas.

@Art how many object do you have when it starts having performance issues?

Hey, right now I am only using one element, but the users can have as many elements as they want. Also, with the current method, it would be harder to zoom to a point as shown here. <- I am trying to achieve this but also keeping the div.canvas infinite at the same time.

@Art ok I saw your expected output, I think you can keep the old code and make the inner of container to have the same background color as .canvas. No need for fancy calculation :)

Yup, if no one else is able to answer, I'll do that.
